# Working with XCode 4.3 installation

Tags: xcode, macos

I installed XCode 4.3 from App Store. When i run the application the xcode version is showing 4.1.
Present my mac version is Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3. Can any tell me the process how to load xcode 4.3.
                                    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Previous versions of Xcode were installed in /Developer. Xcode 4.3 is installed in /Applications. If you haven't removed the old version, then you will have two Xcodes on your system, and your dock icon (if you have one) will likely point to the old one. You should be able to launch Xcode from within /Applications to get 4.3, and I believe it will offer to remove 4.1 from your system.

Comment: I removed the xcode 4.1 in developer-application. When i installed the xcode 4.3 it is storing in developer-application. So kindly tell me the procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install it from LaunchPad.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I will try this one

Answer (score 0):

You may have to explicitly go to the Mac Store and get this update as though it were a new download; it used to come through Apple->Software Update in the past (and I think in the future it will be a Mac Store update that you get just like any other Mac Store update), but this particular transition (4.2->4.3) is a bit more work.